# encrypting with aes in php with padcrypt.php

Tags: php, encoding

I need to create an encryption of some data in php. In the Netsuite documentation which I am reading, it states that
if your post data is `{"id":"373"}`
Using the SHA-1 hashing algorithm would convert it to

```
2274ff3113280bec7e6d777813eaa6806d86b730
```

Then, with 256 symmetric encryption using `AES` algorithm, the `SHA-1` hash becomes

```
sntKRzFdXq5wtaghU5OSXBzVN4jAeS4Tj8e1LPQNmVA=
```

I used padcrypt.php to do the encoding. I was able to produce the same SHA-1 as the documentation. However, I could not created the AES encryption as they have it in the example. I tried changing the padding, I encrypted with base64 but nothing got this number.

Can anyone work backwords from this example and tell me which settings (using padcrypt.php) would create this AES encryption?

Comment: I think we are missing some steps.  `padCrypt` (from what I can see), just adds padding to data based on a block size.  After that you would need to encrypt it, which would be where I'm guessing you use AES encryption?  But at that point, we won't be able to tell you how to get from 'A' to 'B' when we are missing the key the unlocks the way. (ie, we don't have the encryption key you used)

Comment: Thats the problem. The example doesn't give a test encryption key. The only other configurable settings are padding and whether or not you want to convert it to base64, and I'm not sure what I need to do...